# On applying the Layer Cake Representation

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, integration

In the answer to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457797/an-inequality-involving-arctan-of-complex-argument) of mine, an anonymous user invoked the Layer Cake Representation in order to reduce proving
\begin{equation}
\Re\left[ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1+iy}{1+i(y-t)} dG(t)\right]  \ge \Re\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1-it} dG(t)   \right]
\end{equation}
for all $y>0$, to proving 
\begin{equation}
\Re\left[ \int_{-a}^a \frac{1+iy}{1+i(y-t)} dt\right]  \ge 
\Re\left[\int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{1-it} dt   \right]
\end{equation}
for all $y,a>0,$ where $dG$ is the meaure of a symmetric probability distribution (non-increasing on $0 <t<\infty$).

I have Lieb and Loss's analysis text and I think I understand the theorem and the corresponding proof (Theorem 1.13, for reference).

> **My questions are:**
>
> 1. How does one actually use the Layer Cake representation to evaluate integrals over different measures and are there restrictions on measures that make evaluating such integrals easier/harder?
> 2. How was it applied to in the problem above?

Many thanks,

Pete